# Android: How can i develop two products from same code?

Tags: android, git, apk, android-productflavors

We currently offer an Android product to our customers. We are looking to branch our application into two to serve two purposes. But much of the code and the domain layers will be the same. We might add different features henceforth to the two different products.

Maintaining two code repos for these two products wouldn't really cut it because if we were to fix bugs or change things in the domain layer, we'd have to do it twice. Is there a way to deal with this situation?

I did read upon Product flavors. Is this the only solution?

Comment: Same code means the same package?? Check [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-android-examples/tree/master/product-flavors)

Comment: if  there're only small features that different from 2 versions, you can use `flavors`. But if you intend to change a lot, I recommend to create 2 different projects with re-used modules.

Comment: Is your product an Android apk or the software images for a phone or tablet pc?

Comment: You can write code that is common for your different product(flavors) in side main code base  and do product specific in respective flavor folder.
For more and clear info go through-->> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product flavors can be helpful, but isn't always practical if you try to implement different features.
If a large amount of code is going to be equal in both apps, consider moving that code to a library. Then you can create two separate projects to offer different features and use the library in both products. This way you can easily serve two purposes but the common code is still maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

though non-convectional you can use Git to do this have remote repo that carries all the common files/branches clone the repo twice each local repo with common branches and diffrent branches representing where the app differs
all update your remote repo with work from common branch and always merge your local repo from the diffrent branch to common branch hence all common branch will always be carring all that is common while the diffrent branch will be updated from the common branch that is passed from the remote repo to the other project